# Iterate through months by twos in SAS

Tags: sas, datastep

I have the following problem. There are six months of transaction data per entity in a table like this:

```
customer_1  1000  January
customer_1  1000  January
customer_1  1000  February
customer_1  1000  February
customer_1  1000  March
customer_1  1000  April
customer_1  1000  May
customer_1  1000  June
```

I'd like to count the number of transactions in every two months like:

In January - February there are 4 number of transactions.
In February - March there are 3 number of transactions
and so on.

I tried it with nested loops, so that I define a begin and end date and then at the end of the loop I add 1 month to both and iterate again. Something like this:

```
 do i = n to 1 by -1 while (date_key{i} >= begin_date);

        do k = i to 1 by -1 while(date_key{k} >= b_d and date_key{k} <= intnx('Month',b_d,2, 's'));

            if upcase(account{k}) in (&account_type) and
            then do;
                total_amount = sum(total_amount,currency_amount{k});
                amt_cnt = amt_cnt + 1;
            end;
        end;
        if total_amount >= threshold_total then m_cnt = sum(m_cnt,1);
        b_d = intnx('Month',b_d,1,'s');
 end;
```

Comment: Do you have an actual date variable or just that text string with month names?

Comment: Do you want overlapping periods?  That is if you had 12 months of data would you want 6 results or 11 and a half results?

Comment: I have date variables. Yes, I want overlapping periods.

Comment: To iterate over flexible intervals like months it is easier to iterate over an integer offset number and then use INTNX() to calculate the current date for this interval. `do offset=0 to intck('month',start,end);  date=intnx('month',start,offset); .... end;`

Comment: Your example data appears to have nothing to do with the data structure the posted code is using.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I've tried, and it looks almost okay.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably just use a MULTILABEL format and a proc that supports them.

First let's create some actual sample input data.

```
data have ;
  input id :$10. amount date :yymmdd.;
  format date yymmdd.;
cards;
customer_1  1001  2021-01-01
customer_1  1002  2021-01-01
customer_1  1003  2021-02-01
customer_1  1004  2021-02-01
customer_1  1005  2021-03-01
customer_1  1006  2021-04-01
customer_1  1007  2021-05-01
customer_1  1008  2021-06-01
;
```

Then let's create an example format.  Here is a format named PERIODS that are the first 5 two month periods in 2021.

```
proc format cntlout=formats;
 value periods (MULTILABEL)
   '01JAN2021'd -< '01MAR2021'd = '2021 01-02'
   '01FEB2021'd -< '01APR2021'd = '2021 02-03'
   '01MAR2021'd -< '01MAY2021'd = '2021 03-04'
   '01APR2021'd -< '01JUN2021'd = '2021 04-05'
   '01MAY2021'd -< '01JUL2021'd = '2021 05-06'
 ;
run;
```

Once you have the format defined apply it to your DATE variable and summarize by date.

Here is code using PROC SUMMARY.

```
proc summary data=have nway;
  class date / mlf ;
  var amount;
  output out=want(rename=(date=period)) sum= ;
  format date periods.;
run;
proc print data=want;
run;
```

And the results:

[image]

It is not hard to make format dynamically for a range of dates.  You just need these variables in a dataset to use with the CNTLIN= option of PROC FORMAT.

[image]

So perhaps something like this:

```
data cntlin;
  fmtname='PERIODS';
  sexcl='N';
  eexcl='Y';
  hlo='SM';
  length label $20 ;
  do offset=0 to intck('month','01JAN2021'd,'01JAN2022'd)-1;
    start = intnx('month','01JAN2021'd,offset);
    end = intnx('month',start,2);
    label=cat(put(start,yymmd7.),' and ',put(end-1,yymmd7.));
    output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: The problem is that this is inside of a scenario (SAS AML) that uses a huge data step that I cannot modify. This is why I think that the solution could be that I update the variable (b_d in my example) in the iteration somehow.

Comment: Why would it matter how you are creating the input data?  No idea what AML is.  If you want to summarize in an existing data step then would need to know a lot more about the data step.  Summarizing across observations (especially across overlapping sets of observations) is going to be extremely tricky in a data step.  Why not just use the SAS procedures that are designed for that?  If you have SAS/ETS licensed you can also look at the those procedures.  Like PROC EXPAND.